# Deselect ref field in Mongoose model

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In Mongoose, how can I ensure a field is not returned by default - if that field uses a `ref`?

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    // --- Works
    isActive: {
        type: Boolean,
        select: false,
    },

    // --- Does NOT work
    clientsList: [ {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Client',
        select: false,
    }],
});
```

If I retrieve this user with `User.findById`, then the returned User object will not include `isActive` (as expected), but will include `clientsList` (not expected).

**Is there a way to deselect the second field as well?**

PS: I understand that I can manually do `.select('-clientsList')` at the query level, but would prefer to deselect it add the model level, similar to the first field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exclude the array itself, you are currently excluding the values inside the array.

To fix it, just change your clientList definition like this:

```
  clientsList: {
    type: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Client",
        select: false
      }
    ],
    select: false
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the problem by declaring the `clientsList` field like this:

```
clientsList: {
  type: [ {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Salary'
  }],
  select: false,
}
```